# Finding API to get random Quotes and images from website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, api

this is Antika. I have started learning to code since a few days back, and am only familiar with HTML/CSS and basics of JS.

**Developer Level:** Beginner

I have recently found this. https://winterly.app/ 
This is a **react based website**.

**Feature I am looking for :**  
I see **new photos and quote Every time** it loads.

**Question :**
I want to get the `js script` this site uses to fetch these?

I tried to search for it in the developer tools (in Chrome), but I am not familiar with react and have very little experience in programming.

I'm looking for the exact script the site uses, which must be present in it's source, but I'm having a hard time locating it.

I would love if someone can help me with that.

Comment: this may useful for you https://quotes.rest/

Comment: Thank you @nagendranag . But it says there it's a paid API. Will it be possible to get the exact script code from the developer tools?

Comment: https://theysaidso.com/api/

Comment: Generally, you would not examine the JS code of a Web application because it's obfuscated in modern websites, so it's hard to read. An easier approach is to open the network tab in the developer settings and examine which requests go over the network and what's their form. By this, you'll be able to analyze how a website communicates with its server(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For random quotes

https://winterly-backend.herokuapp.com/quote

For random images

https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature

Comment: Thank you so much Shaikh, This is exactly what I needed. ❤️